# Disable infragistics ultragrid validation popups

Tags: validation, popup, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm working on an application where I copy data from excel into an ultragrid.

When I paste wrong data (for example I paste a string into a column that expects an integer) I get a popup from the ultragrid displaying the paste error.

I want to make my own validation without popups.

Is there a way to turn these popups off?

greetings

Gert

(at design time I created an ultradatasource to configure the ultragrid)

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to answer my own questions in the first 8 hours after posting my answer. Will post the solution as an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Don't worry. Just trying to keep a good score for this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution for the problem (thanx for answering, it brought me in the right line of thinking) This is what solved it:

```
private void ugData_Error(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void ultraGrid1_CellDataError(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    e.RaiseErrorEvent = false;
    e.StayInEditMode = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply. The popup is still there though.